# Android Image Button to close popup

Tags: android

The following code just doesn't want to work. Hoping someone can see what is wrong with it because I can't see what is missing.
Thanks in advance.

In the java file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Dialogue extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.dialogue);

        ImageButton btnClose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in the xml file:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@id/btnClose"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_close"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

Comment: in your xml file set id of ImageButton as `@+id/btnClose` not `@id`

Comment: i think the problem is here android:id="@id/btnClose" change it to  android:id="@+id/btnClose"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this set id like this `android:id="@+id/btnClose"`

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_close"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh, I didn't see the typing error, had been staring at it for too long

Comment: @ACP did it work..?

Comment: Yes thanks for your help

Comment: @ACP you're welcome Don't forget to upvote also

Answer (score 1):

**You have to only Change your id like this:**

`android:id="@+id/btnClose"`

Thanks!